# Get classname integer if it exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

so im trying to get the offset of an element set by tis class. (anyone familiar with twitter bootstrap will recognise this)

at the moment im doing this:

```
 offset = $el.attr('class').match(/(?:col-lg-offset-)[0-9]{1,2}/).toString().subString(14);
```

which works fine if the element has a class of col-lg-offset-* but when it doesnt this errors.  Now I could wrap this in an if statement with something like:

```
if ($el.hasClass('col-lg-offset-*'))
```

but that doesnt seem very clean to me, often when defining variables I use:

```
var example = option1 || option2
```

However this wont work. Is there another way I can do this? also any suggestions to improve the offset number selection, as using a .match() doesn't seem like the best way to do this?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return array of `String#match` first before calling methods on it:

```
m = $el.attr('class').match(/(?:col-lg-offset-)[0-9]{1,2}/);
if (m) { 
    offset = m.toString().subString(14);
}
```